# Why is my AFNetworking API call result in an error?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I come from a Swift background; therefore, am used to Alamofire. I am trying to learn Objective-C and have been plying with AFNetworking.

The following is a simple method that calls the Yelp search API to find business in the vicinity.

```
- (void) getBusinesses: (NSString *) usingToken{

    NSString *starbucks = @"Starbucks";
    NSString *latitude = @""; //enter latitude
    NSString *longitude = @""; //enter longitude

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=%@&latitude=%@&longitude=%@", starbucks, latitude, longitude];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer alloc] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:nil error:nil];
    NSString *bearerToken = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Bearer %@", usingToken];
    [request setValue: bearerToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error){
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"*** Failed!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"*** Succeeded!");
        }
    }];

    dataTask.resume;
}
```

When running this code I get the following error:

`Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatibility mapping behavior in the near future.`

I have tested the above Yelp URL with my valid access token on Postman and it works perfectly.

If someone could point me in the right direction to figure out what is going on I'd appreciate it!

P.S. this is the documentation for the [Yelp search endpoint](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search)

Comment: I think that this line is causing issue: `[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer alloc] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:nil error:nil];` You are not calling the `init`. So you need to do: ` `AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]` (or `[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer  alloc] init]`. Then `manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer` (but may be optional do to so), and `NSURLRequest *request = [requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:nil error:nil];`

Comment: @Larme That was the problem. Merci!